# Why am I getting an unsupported operand error here?

Tags: syntax-error

```
x = input("Pick a number from 1 to 5 ")
print("You chose " + x + "!")
prev = int(x-1)
print("The number before it is "+ prev)
```

Why does this code not run?  It gives an error in line 3

Comment: "int(x-1)" appears to be undefined. Please include the programming language that you are using and the complete code listing applicable to your question.

Comment: Never mind.  I figured it out.  The input was giving me a string.  When I put int(input(), it gives me an integer and it works.